# Someone knows how to implement the client in GCM

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, cloud, messaging

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http
I already have the client but I dont know how to implement the server.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Build an app-engine project at [this site](https://appengine.google.com/).(Follow google documentation)

2.Install 'Google plugin' for eclipse(android studio dose not need it i guess)

3.Make sure if using correct java version for compilation and other necessities in documentation

4.Make an android project.Right Click on your project>Google>Generate App Engine Backend

5.Google plugin will make the client usable via end-points